# RESTful Java client convert JSON responses to Objects

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, jersey

EDITED:

I am trying to convert the JSON responses that i am getting from REST API service to objects inside my application. I use Jersey to perform “GET” requests to REST the service.

Lets say that i have the following two API calls, each one having its corresponding JSON response as:

**First call**: Get a specific myEntity object with its code value: https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get?code=BOBS-JC6L (GET)

**Response**:

```
{
  "isOk": 1,
  "isAuthError": 0,
  "error": false,
  "myEntity":{
        "id": "123",
        "code": "BOBS-JC6L",
        "type": "ZZZ",
        "value": "15.00", 
    }
}
```

**Second call**: Get all myEntity objects:  https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get-all (GET)

**Response**:

```
{
  "isOk": 1,
  "isAuthError": 0,
  "error": false,
  "myEntities": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "code": "BOBS-JC6L",
        "type": "ZZZ",
        "value": "15.00",      
    },
    {
        "id": "456",
        "code": "BOBS-JC7L",
        "type": "CCC",
        "value": "32.00",
    }
    {...}
  ]
}
```

So in both cases the fundamental object (of type MyEntity) is included in JSON as nested element(s). I am trying to map JSON structure into POJO objects.

So i have created the following POJO classes:

MyEntity POJO (this is the fundamental nested element(s) class):

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

public class MyEntity {

    private int id;
    private String code;
    private String type;
    private BigDecimal value;

    public MyEntity(){

    }

    public MyEntity(String code, String type, BigDecimal value){
        this.code = code;
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    ....

}
```

Then there is a class for the first API call response (we get a single MyEntity object):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GetSingleMyEntityResponse {

    private int isOk;
    private int isAuthError;
    private boolean error;
    private MyEntity myEntity;

    ...

}
```

And another class for the second API call response (we get multiple nested MyEntity objects):

```
@XmlRootElement
public class GetMultipleMyEntityResponse {

    private int isOk;
    private int isAuthError;
    private boolean error;
    private List<MyEntity> myEntities;

    ...

}
```

In my code i first try to get a single myEntity object, calling: https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get?code=BOBS-JC6L

```
try {

      ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
      Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

      WebResource webResource1 = client
              .resource("https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get?code=MESM-ZB2NEJ");

      Builder builder = webResource1.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) //
              .header("content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

      ClientResponse response = builder.get(ClientResponse.class);

      // Status 200 is successful.
      if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
          System.out.println("Failed with HTTP Error code: " + response.getStatus());
          String error = response.getEntity(String.class);
          System.out.println("Error: " + error);
          return;
      }

      System.out.println("\n\nOutput from Server .... \n");

      GetSingleMyEntityResponse vResp = (GetSingleMyEntityResponse) response.getEntity(GetSingleMyEntityResponse.class);
      MyEntity v = vResp.getMyEntity();

      if(v.getId()>0) {
          System.out.println("Id .... " + v.getId());
          System.out.println("Code .... " + v.getCode());
          System.out.println("Type .... " + v.getType());      
          System.out.println("Value .... " + v.getValue());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works and i am able to get MyEntity object:

```
Output from Server .... 

Id .... 123
Code .... BOBS-JC6L
Type .... ZZZ
Value .... 15.00
```

I am also trying to map multiple MyEntity objects from:
https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get-all

```
try {

            Client client = Client.create();

            WebResource webResource = client
               .resource("https://www.test.com/webservice/entity/get-all");

            ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
                       .get(ClientResponse.class);

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + response.getStatus());
            }

            String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

            GetMultipleMyEntityResponse vResp = (GetMultipleMyEntityResponse) response.getEntity(GetMultipleMyEntityResponse.class);
            List<MyEntity> vRespList = new ArrayList<>();
            vRespList = vResp.getMyEntities();

            if(vRespList.size()>0) {

                for(MyEntity v:vRespList) {
                    System.out.println("Id .... " + v.getId());
                    System.out.println("Code .... " + v.getCode());
                    System.out.println("Type .... " + v.getType());      
                    System.out.println("Value .... " + v.getValue());
                }

            }

          } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

}
```

But is seems that the GetMultipleMyEntityResponse POJO class is not working for it, and i am getting:

j

```
avax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:553)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506)
    at com.mspos.mesmo.JerseyClientGet.main(JerseyClientGet.java:97)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Error creating JSON-based XMLStreamReader
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: stream is closed]
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.createXmlStreamReader(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:125)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.ensureNonEmptyReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:173)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:111)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.createXmlStreamReader(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:113)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.ensureNonEmptyReader(Stax2JsonFactory.java:167)
    ... 10 more
```

Any ideas of what am i missing?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using the Jersey client instead of Spring RestTemplate or Retrofit?

Comment: I am new to RESTful with Java and from a first look it seemed to me quite straightforward. I will take a look on your proposals and thank for the info!

Comment: Your response clearly doesn't match the structure of MyEntity. Look at the JSON: the object you receive is not a MyEntity. it's a MyEntity wrapped into another object with fields isOk, error, etc.

Comment: You are right @JBNizet ... i see .So maybe i could grab the part of the JSON i need by using something like the Jakson Object mapper: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial ?

Comment: You probably already use it (or an equivalent), since Jersey is mapping the JSON to an object already. But you need to use the correct class, which matches with the structure of the response.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! I have now changed my POJO classes to map the JSON structure. I am able to get a single MyEntity object but i can not map JSON structure with multiple myEntity elements into a List...

Comment: You're calling response.getEntity() twice. Call it only once.

Comment: :) ... That was so obvious and simple ... Thansk @JBNizet ... If you post an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `response.getEntity()` twice. Call it only once.